# Where to deploy scripts in a sandbox solution?

Tags: web-part, sandbox-solution, office-365

I have a webpart deployed as a sandbox solution. The webpart has resource files, javascript files, css styles, and images.  Where would I deploy all these in a sandbox solution (Office 365)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and found this answer: http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/06/30/embedding-resources-in-sandbox-solutions/

This works for all my files, except the resource files...Not sure how I would do those

Answer (score 2):

In my 365 projects, I created a folder called "Modules" inside the "Modules" folder I created another folder called "Scripts", "Images" and "Css", and I put my files in theses folder.

You can create a class what inherits a WebPart and create an override method for OnInit. From there you can create a new literal control

```
Controls.AddAt(0, new LiteralControl("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"" + WebUrl + "/path_your_module/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js\"><\\/script>');</script>"));
```

WebUrl is a property with the url of your site.

Don't forget to inherit it in your webpart within the class you created!

Answer (score 1):

This article is about localization in Sandbox, but it shows the method to access the resource files properly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615453.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use Style library and make a folder for every category like images,scripts,styles